# How would you sever the material plane from the rest?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, story

I won't bore you with my world and plot details, but the end goal for the BBEG is to cut the material plane entirely from the other planes, thereby:

Eliminating all forms of magic

Preventing gods and beings from the other planes ever interacting with the material plane again

Basically turning the place into our Earth (a villainous goal indeed)

But I'm not too familiar with any D&D planar lore, and am wondering if there is any precedence or potential for this in any lore that you know?

Comment: We don't really handle open-ended requests for ideas here, but questions that can be answered definitively. Have you tried a [forum](//meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)?

Comment: One of my questions is if this is something that has been covered in DnD lore previously at all? If the answer is no, or you don't deal with lore here, then fair enough :)

Comment: You probably could cut this down to a question *only* about precedent, especially if you pick a setting (there's, what, a dozen published semi-official settings?). But as it is, it's also asking for suggestions beyond that, which isn't really going to work so well.

Comment: "Prevent planar travel" and "eliminate all forms of magic" are different goals, and neither one necessarily causes the other.

Comment: @TuggyNE,Im happy to do that. I'm running Homebrew that's loosely based on DnD cosmology, so am happy to use ideas from anywhere

Comment: @Topquark, that is exactly the kind of information I'm looking for! I didn't know that, why is that the case? I figured that magic come from the positive, negative, elemental etc planes?

Comment: @Hope_my_PCs_dont_read If that's your question, why don't you edit your question accordingly? You will then receive your answers! :)

Comment: I have edited my question since I posted it, I'm not sure how else I should change it now. What isn't clear? You think I should instead ask multiple more precise questions?

Comment: "Where magic comes from" is open ended, but since this is your home brew world if you choose to decide that it comes from all other planes  then that is where it comes from.   The other issue is druids: their magic comes from "nature" in a lot of D&D lore, and I am not sure how you account for that in your basis for separation from planes influencing their magic.

Comment: Okay thank you, I guess I'm fundamentally misunderstanding D&D lore regarding magic, I'll try and do some wiki reading.